# Going to second activity by password

Tags: android

I am new to coding.I want to code
in order to go to second activity using a button,
an editText and a pasdword in case it maches.
But it does n`t work.Please help me.Following is my code:

package com.mycompany.myapp;

```
import android.app.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.view.*;
import android.view.View.*;
import android.widget.*;
public class MainActivity extends Activity 
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        EditText eText=            (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mainEditText1);
        String myCode=eText.getText().toString();
    Button nextPage=    (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
    if(myCode.equals("Titan")){
        nextPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.
                                 this,actor.class));
    }
    });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: "But id does n`t work.Please help me." is not a useful problem description. What happens and what did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: you can move your clicklistener outside your if.

Answer (score 1):

Move your condition and `getText()` call in listener

```
    nextPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            String myCode=eText.getText().toString();
            if(myCode.equals("Titan")){
                startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.
                             this,actor.class));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I moved condition and getText() into listener and it worked.Thank you all.

Answer (score 1):

So, here's what's happening:

- You have an `EditText` field in your app, where the user types their password.
- You capture that `EditText` in your code using `EditText eText = ...`
- You then check to see if `eText.equals("Titan");`
- If it matches `Titan`, you see the `onClick` listener.

But, when this code is ran, the `EditText` is always empty, so you never set the onClick listener!

The fix is fairly straightforward:

```
    nextPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
             String myCode=eText.getText().toString();

             if(myCode.equals("Titan")) {
                   startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,actor.class));
             } 
        }
    });
```

Now, when the button is clicked:

- You capture the value of `eText` as `myCode`.
- You check if `myCode` is equal to `Titan`
- If `true` (ie it matches), you then run `startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this,actor.class));`

Answer (score -1):

You have written class name **actor.class starting with a smaller case**. Make it **starts with uppercase Actor.class**. Bellow is the answer to your questions.

```
 Button nextPage = (Button)findViewById(R.id.mainButton1);
 nextPage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
            String myCode=eText.getText().toString();
            if(myCode.equals("Titan"))
            {
             startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.
                                 this,Actor.class));
            }else{
            //password not matching
     }
    });
```